# How can I display a div if a user is using a browser not supported by Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website based on [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com) (which has dropped support for IE7 and older and Firefox 3.6 and older browsers). I have no problem with this but I'm looking for a simple script to display a div with a warning message telling visitors to my site why it looks odd in their old browser.

I came across [this script](http://browser-update.org/) which is useful except it displays a predefined message whereas I want to customise a div to display (to better fit the theme of my site).

Rather than reinvent the wheel - does anybody know of a simple script to do this?

Comment: You can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) in IE, which is clean (enough) and pretty simple. For FireFox you'll have to use a bit of JavaScript to get the browser's version, or do some feature detection based on a feature only available in 3.6 and older

Comment: Firefox 3.6 only accounts for [0.56%](http://www.netmarketshare.com/report.aspx?qprid=3&qpaf=&qpcustom=Firefox+3.6&qpcustomb=0) of browsers used as of June 2013, so you may want to consider ignoring 3.6 if it's a lot of effort to show a message

Comment: Ideally instead of just seeing the browser, you should test all the functions and whether they are supported in the user's browser. But since it's bootstrap and they say it's not for IE7 anymore, I guess just testing for IE7 or below will be a simple yet good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.
also see this post: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <p>Please use a modern browser!!!</p>
<![endif]-->
```

TJL

Comment: Whilst this doesn't tackle the Firefox issue, IE users vastly outnumber them and this is a very elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily customize the info-box's styles and layout using the linked script. Just look [here](http://browser-update.org/customize.html).

---

If you want even more customization, you can use the script provided on [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Just copy this whole script into your js-file (after the page has been loaded --> document is ready)

```
var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            var dataProp = data[i].prop;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
            else if (dataProp)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index == -1) return;
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Chrome",
            identity: "Chrome"
        },
        {   string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "OmniWeb",
            versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
            identity: "OmniWeb"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Apple",
            identity: "Safari",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            prop: window.opera,
            identity: "Opera",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "iCab",
            identity: "iCab"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "KDE",
            identity: "Konqueror"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Firefox",
            identity: "Firefox"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Camino",
            identity: "Camino"
        },
        {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Netscape",
            identity: "Netscape"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "MSIE",
            identity: "Explorer",
            versionSearch: "MSIE"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Gecko",
            identity: "Mozilla",
            versionSearch: "rv"
        },
        {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Mozilla",
            identity: "Netscape",
            versionSearch: "Mozilla"
        }
    ],
    dataOS : [
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Win",
            identity: "Windows"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Mac",
            identity: "Mac"
        },
        {
               string: navigator.userAgent,
               subString: "iPhone",
               identity: "iPhone/iPod"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Linux",
            identity: "Linux"
        }
    ]

};
BrowserDetect.init();
```

Aftewards you can easily get the Browser and version using `BrowserDetect.browser` and `BrowserDetect.version` and then hide or show the info-box accordingly (easiest with jQuery as it is already used within Bootstrap)